# c++ code coverage tool for windows and linux

Tags: windows, linux, c++, software-testing, code-coverage

I'm aware of many solutions in linux and many visual studio solutions in windows, however this project will have developers simultaneously working in windows and linux and as such, code coverage needs to support both.

Much of the testing tests the whole system - evaluating the outputs for accuracy and compliance to requirements - it's also mostly entirely data driven.

There are very few actual unit tests.

It's not ideal to have two separate tools but that's what I'm currently thinking about doing. Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: "` this project will have developers simultaneously working in windows and linux`" - just curious as to why?

Comment: Could you use Cygwin or Wine?  E.g use Cygwin in Windows and run `gcov` on both O.Ses